# Listening for only remote value events in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using a Firebase database, I have implemented a very basic test case:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var test1Ref = firebase.database().ref('messages/test1');    

test1Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log( "Firebase database 'test1' value changed, new value: " + snapshot.val().message );
});


function sendMessage(message){
    test1Ref.set({
        message: message
    });   
}
```

However, I only want to listen to "remote" changes, i.e. when the data actually changes **on the Firebase database server**.

It turns out that the above script keeps working even if I disconnect my computer from the Internet, so that seems to indicate that the Firebase SDK is triggering the event locally, instead of (as I previously expected) when the data actually changes on the server.

My goal is to create a simple benchmark to measure the time it takes to perform an update from the client to the server and get an update back to the client. If the event is triggered locally, obviously the delay is practically non-existent and doesn't tell me anything about the actual time for the update to travel from client->server->client.

I guess one solution would be to use two separate clients running on the same machine, but it would be neater to keep it all in one place.